# Jsoup XML parse from File

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jsoup

I need to transform an XML file to parse XML in Jsoup.
I have an XML file that the way it is now, is to parse HTML and not XML.
Anyone know a way?
In HTML, the jsoup works very well, I have no idea how to include a file and use XML Parse this file.

Anyone know how to do, because the site Jsoup not think anything related to XML or XML file conversion.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a proper XML parser such as [JDom](http://www.jdom.org/) instead of Jsoup, which is, as you say, an HTML parser.

Comment: But Jsoup supports XML, just knowing I'm not using